# mysql - update, multiple table join, set value from case expression

Tags: mysql

**Given below is the update query: 
Relation between tables:

- card_order to order - many to one.
- order to customer - one to one.
- customer to fees - one to many.
  When setting the value the case expression invariably evaluates to the else of the expression, even if when clause satisfies. Please help

  ```
  update card_orders cbi
      join orders ord on cbi.card_order_no = ord.order_no
      join customers cust on cust.id = ord.customerid 
      join fees fee on fee.customerid = cust.id 
              and active = 1
  set cbi.fee1 =  
      CASE WHEN fee.id = 4 and fee.amount > 0 THEN fee.amount 
      ELSE 'NO FEE' END   
  where cbi.card_order_no = 10250;
  ```

//fee.amount is mysql decimal datatype
When setting the value the case expression invariably evaluates to the else of the expression, even if when clause satisfies.
 The update also sets value to some columns in the order table

The update query is to be used inside a stored procedure
**

Comment: Hi, if you replace the set cbi.feel = with SELECT and run the query directly inside of mysql, is it displaying correctly?  This will help determine if something is going wrong in your update query or if the issue is within your case statement.  Thanks.

Comment: when I try fee1 ='7.00' it updates but with select query its not getting updated. so most likely an issue with the joins ?

Answer (score 0):

With that last one-to-many, customer to fees, you can't really control which fee record gets used (UPDATE only updates each record once, so multiple matches won't each update separately; and, even if they did, the later matches would be overwriting the previous ones' changes).

You could LEFT JOIN to fees, adding the criteria from your case...

```
UPDATE card_orders AS cbi
    INNER JOIN orders AS ord ON cbi.card_order_no = ord.order_no
    INNER JOIN customers AS cust ON cust.id = ord.customerid 
    LEFT JOIN fees AS fee1 
            ON fee1.customerid = cust.id AND fee1.active = 1
            AND fee1.id = 4 AND fee1.amount > 0
    LEFT JOIN fees AS feeX 
            ON feeX.customerid = cust.id AND feeX.active = 1
            AND feeX.id = Y AND feeX.amount > 0 
            -- or whatever feeX's case conditions would have been
SET cbi.fee1 = CASE WHEN fee1.customerid IS NOT NULL THEN fee1.amount ELSE 'NO FEE' END
  , cbi.feeX = CASE WHEN feeX.customerid IS NOT NULL THEN feeX.amount ELSE 'NO FEE' END
WHERE cbi.card_order_no = 10250
;
```

This version is slightly semantically different though. Your original version would only update card_orders entries that had links to at least one fee entry; this version will include entries without any fees linked.

Comment: Thanks. I can do that if that's the only fee that is getting updated.. I have more columns like cbi.fee2, cbi.fee3 etc each getting updated based on the fee id column.I just gave a simpler version of the query in the post

Comment: @Hstan You can do that with multiple joins, see edit for "feeX".